# ISO 8859-15 to UTF-8 conversion in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, iso, iso-8859-15

My string is "Die ARD hat eines der gr=F6=DFten Korrespondentennetze weltweit.". I guess itsISO 8859-15 and I want to convert it in utf-8. which will be "Die ARD hat eines der größten Korrespondentennetze weltweit."

I tried the several ways:

```
iconv("ISO-8859-15", "UTF-8", $content);
```

But, its not working, please guide further or let me know some ready made function for this conversion.

Comment: did your server loaded iconv module? enable error reporting to see what is going on

Comment: That's not any text encoding. It's a transport encoding; I'm guessing some email encoding. `iconv` won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

The quoted text is in an email transport encoding called "Quoted Printable". ISO-8859-15 may be the underlying text encoding, but best look at the email headers.